# Horizontal stacking same index in numpy N dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a more pythonic/smarter/efficient way to create a new numpy array where each element is the horizontal stack of the N elements at the same position?

example input:

```
a = [
 [ 0.29425778  0.69311652]
 [ 1.64811132 -0.21107166]
] 
b = [
  [ 0.15356808 -1.00027092]
  [[-1.578063    0.29741589]
]
```

result:

```
[
  array([0.29425778, 0.15356808]), 
  array([ 0.69311652, -1.00027092]), 
  array([ 1.64811132, -1.578063  ]), 
  array([-0.21107166,  0.29741589])
]
```

Right now I just use a nested for loop and it obviously works.

cheers, 
FB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy.dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) and [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.29425778, 0.69311652], [1.64811132, -0.21107166]])
b = np.array([[0.15356808, -1.00027092],[-1.578063, 0.29741589]])

result = np.dstack((a, b)).reshape(-1, 2)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 0.29425778  0.15356808]
 [ 0.69311652 -1.00027092]
 [ 1.64811132 -1.578063  ]
 [-0.21107166  0.29741589]]
```